# How to make simple for-loop consuming less memory?

Tags: python, performance, memory-efficient

```
def odd():
    for i in xrange(0, 100):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            print i
```

I have this small function. 
I would like to know:

1. If there is a way to make it consume less memory?
2. What are the tools and techniques you can use to efficiently measure and improve memory consumption?

I have this question in mind after looking at the following question: [odd numbers](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/25/)

Comment: why -1? please give an explanation :)

Comment: you're already using xrange, so that helps, I assume this is in python 2 then?

Comment: +1: I wonder too, about the -1. I must note that this loop consumes almost no memory, and would not consume more if the upper limit was much larger. I would also like to note that you can write more simply `xrange(100)` and `if i % 2:`.

Comment: Why not xrange(1, 100, 2)? This will give you odd numbers at once...

Comment: About the -1 (which is not mine): I can guess that because the memory consumption measurement question has been asked a few times on Stackoverflow (I can think of two instances), this may be a way of suggesting that you first search better on the site before asking a question. This is a suggestion I would like to make. :)

Comment: i gave you an upvote to counteract the jerk even though I dont think your question has a decent answer

Comment: If you don't already know part 2 (how to measure memory consumption), why are you asking part 1 at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recent [answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984104/42973) about memory consumption measurement.

As for the memory consumption of your loop, it is negligible, and does not depend on the upper bound of the range, since `xrange()` does not really store much more than the next value it will return.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the question if is actually about memory consumption and an algorithm to make it more efficient or if it's tied to a specific language and how it does things in the background.

If it's about memory consumption and an algorithm to improve the solution a good workaround is to use a recursive (or iterative) solution with some simple conditionals.

Example instead of going through the 100 numbers in your loop (im not a python dev so ill write this easy solution in javascript that can be easily tested in chrome's console) you can try something like this:

```
    var iteration = 0;
var odd = function(val,max){
    iteration++;
    //base case
    if ( val > max ) return;
    if ( val % 2 == 1 ){
        console.log(val);
        odd(val+2,max);
    }else odd(val+1,max);   
}

odd(0,100);
console.log("Total iterations: "+iteration);
```

It results in only going through 52 iterations instead the 100.

Comment: The question has a Python tag, so it's about Python. Plus, if one wants to only get odd numbers and limit the number of iterations, one can simply iterate from 1 in increments of 2, as mentioned in one of the comments to the original question. Furthermore, the question is about reducing memory consumption, and your recursive solution uses O(n) memory, which is much worse than the O(1) memory of the question.